# Button states in quiz application

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am making a quiz similar to buzzfeed quizzes like [THIS](http://www.buzzfeed.com/candacelowry/which-walking-dead-survivor-are-you). I have the logic planned out and I can kind of see how I'm supposed to code it to act similarly to the one in the link, but I have a problem with the button states.

Here is a fiddle of my code: [sample quiz](http://jsfiddle.net/ZRRz7/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btn1, #a1').click(function () {
                   $('#a1').removeClass("fadeout");                    
                   $('#a1').addClass("highlight");

                    $('#a2').removeClass("highlight");  
                    $('#a3').removeClass("highlight");  
                    $('#a4').removeClass("highlight");  
                    $('#a5').removeClass("highlight");  
                    $('#a6').removeClass("highlight");  
                   $('#a2').addClass("fadeout");
                   $('#a3').addClass("fadeout");
                   $('#a4').addClass("fadeout");
                   $('#a5').addClass("fadeout");
                   $('#a6').addClass("fadeout");
                   btn1.checked = "true";
                   btn2.checked = "";
                   btn3.checked = "";
                   btn4.checked = "";
                   btn5.checked = "";
                   btn6.checked = "";
                   window.alert(document.write(getElementById("btn1").value));
```

Coding a single question does not seem to be a problem with the ff: change color on hover, reduce opacity of other choices, change to color blue once selected, etc... but as I add more questions, I realized I would have to use addClass and removeClass for the button's effects for every choice for every question, which, as you can see, wouldn't be so practical to code.

Are there any other more efficient ways to do this?

Comment: Yes, yes there is. It involves restructuring your code to use array and loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the click event of the question div you can apply the classes by using the `$this` keyword.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.a_choice').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("highlight");
        $(this).siblings().addClass("fadeout");

        $(this).children('input').prop('checked', true);
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
        $(this).removeClass("fadeout");
    });
});
```

See http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

Comment: Thank you very much! The jquery functions .sibling() and .children were exactly what I was looking for! The sample code you provided also helped me understand their concept. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to each button and get them by class instead of by id

```
$('.quizbuttons').removeClass("fadeout");
```

The buttons should have the class "quizbuttons" like:

```
<button class="quizbuttons"></button>
```

Or whatever element you are using.

Best.